# Counterexample for converse about measurable sections

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

On page 67 of Jacod and Protter, *Probability Essentials*, it is stated that:

> **Theorem 10.2** Let $f$ be measurable: $(E \times F, {\cal E} \otimes {\cal F}) \to (\mathbf R, {\cal R})$. For each $x \in E$ (respt. $y \in F$), the "section" $y \to f(x,y)$ (resp. $x \to f(x,y)$) is an $\cal F$-measurable (resp. $\cal E$-measurable) function.
>
> *Note*: The converse to Theorem 10.2 is false in general.

What is a counterexample to the converse of Theorem 10.2?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89375/sections-measure-zero-imply-set-is-measure-zero